# Jenkins setting From address - running shell script from job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I may not have my terminology correct but here goes...   Total Jenkins newbie here.
I am testing Jenkins to see if we can run internal shell scripts for various tasks my team has to perform periodically in our organization.  I created a new "test" project and set it to execute a shell script during the Build step.  I set a parameter on the project it will set a To address as the first argument for the script in the Build step.  When I build it, the script runs fine and sends the email.

The issue is the email is sent from "Jenkins <jenkins@jenkins>" which looks like it's following the user@hostname format (server it's from run is called "jenkins").  In my script I am setting the "from" address to dev1@somewhere.org.  Is there a way to have Jenkins use the "from" address in my script (instead of "Jenkins <jenkins@jenkins>")?  Is there a config file where this is set for Jenkins?

Note:  I am getting system notifications fine for things like build failures from "dev1@somewhere.org" because I set it as the Reply-To Address in Email Notification settings.   I am using mailx on the server and ssmtp if that makes any difference.

Here's the script I have set for the build step in my Jenkins project...

```
#!/bin/bash

emailto=$1

from="dev1@somewhere.org"
to=$emailto
bcc="dev2@somewhere.org"
subject="TEST EMAIL"
body=$'This is the body of our email.\nHere is a Second line of text.\n\n'\
'Lastly, a Third line of text.'


mail -s "$subject" -b "$bcc" -r "$from" "$to" <<< "$body"
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a alias for the "jenkins" user in the SSMTP configuration so the user was aliased to "dev1@somewhere.org".  That way the From address for scripts run from Jenkins and send email have from address dev1@somewhere.org.  See this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643873/how-to-get-ssmtp-to-map-local-user-to-email-address-for-the-to-field).